# How to force widgets with grid with different width (tkinter)

Tags: tkinter, grid, width, center

I'm trying to create a GUI with `tkinter` which controls some ports with ON/OFF toggle. I have a frame which has a Text label and 4 buttons underneath it.

[image: layout here]

I have an issue with `grid()` placement. The frame text bigger, on row=0 and column =0.
Button titles  are on row=1 and consecutive columns (with some padding).
And buttons same as tittles but with row=2.

The first button with its title will be placed in a space as wide as the text title above (`sticky='w'`). I've read that :*"The column will default to the smallest width that will accommodate the widest item. That, or elsewhere in your code you give a non-zero weight to some of those columns that is causing them to expand*"

**Issue**:
I want all buttons to be towards the left, and s2 to be placed after the end of s1 with same padding as the others. I do not want s1 with its title to be in a cell as wide as the cell above.

How could I achieve this? Can I use the weight parameter?

One idea I have is to create another frame within this frame that has only the buttons and place it on row=1,column=0.

Thanks!

I've tried on all my titles and buttons with sticky='w', it works only on S1 with its title, but not on the rest.

Comment: add `columnspan=4` to `.grid(...)` on the top label/frame.

Comment: If you want to move s1 to right so that it's next to s2, just add `"sticky=e"` to only s1. If you want to move s2, s3, ... to the left so that they are next to s1, look at the comment above.

Comment: @acw1668 that was it! I added column span to the Title label that was taking up space. When saying "top label/frame" do you mean the top text I had with Ports Control, or the top frame which contains all the buttons and titles?

Comment: As you don't post any code and you mention *"I have a frame which has a Text label"*, so I said *top label/frame* as I don't know whether it is just a label or a label inside a frame.

Comment: It's a label (along with the buttons) within a frame. and the Frame has master a root (root = tk.TK() ). Either way, you helped me solve it, so thanks for that! we can mark it as an answer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.